# Exponents are not getting add

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a beginner in Mathematica and learning from Google.

I was trying to find the determinant of a 4*4 matrix.

```
TT = {{ap, b, c, d}, {e, fp, g, h}, {i, j, kp, l}, {m, n, o, pq}}
TT // MatrixForm
```

After it, I applied determinant command.

```
Det[TT]
```

I am getting result as follow,

```
d g j m - c h j m - d fp kp m + b h kp m + c fp l m - b g l m -  d g i n + c h i n + d e kp n - ap h kp n - c e l n + ap g l n + d fp i o - b h i o - d e j o + ap h j o + b e l o - ap fp l o -  c fp i pq + b g i pq + c e j pq - ap g j pq - b e kp pq + ap fp kp pq
```

I want above expression as a polynomial in `p`, want to collect coefficients separately. I have tried various command such as `Collect`, `Factor` etc. But each time I get the answer as the same polynomial as above.

Comment: there is no `p` in your input expression.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `a*p`, `f*p`, `k*p`, `p*q`, instead of `ap`, `fp`, `kp` and `pq`.

Mathematica needs either space or multiple sign to treat them as a separate multiplier and not as a variable.

```
t = {{a p, b, c, d}, {e, f p, g, h}, {i, j, k p, l}, {m, n, o,
     p q}};
Collect[Det[t], p]
(* d g j m - c h j m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n - c e l n - 
 b h i o - d e j o + b e l o + a f k p^4 q + 
 p (b h k m + c f l m + d e k n + a g l n + d f i o + a h j o + 
    b g i q + c e j q) + 
 p^2 (-d f k m - a h k n - a f l o - c f i q - a g j q - b e k q) *)
```